# Rails+Devise password reset token expires before the configured time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

```
Rails Version: 5.0.0.1
Devise Version: 4.2
```

In my devise.rb file I define lifetime for password token to be 6 hours

```
  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
```

When I opt for password reset through the Forgot Password link, I can see the timestamp and token generated

```
postgres=> select reset_password_token, reset_password_sent_at from users where email='email@gmail.com';
                       reset_password_token                       |   reset_password_sent_at
------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------
 89f51bce1bc6b495c16a50b015d03897d0520a8b58c300a5deef16b2c45cac82 | 2016-09-16 21:18:01.322362
```

Active record and application timezone are both set to `'Asia/Kolkata'` but when I click on the link delivered in email and try changing password (which is within minutes of the email delivered) the password change fails with message

Reset password token has expired, please request a new one

***Update One***
I have `recoverable` enabled in the user model, but to no use here.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable
end
```

***Update Two***

Here are the logs from after implementing changes suggested in answer

Updated devise config to

```
# Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
# Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
# change their passwords.
config.reset_password_within = 6.hours.from_now
```

The password update still fails, no real error in the logs neither.

```
I, [2016-09-19T20:54:04.793217 #19146]  INFO -- : Started PUT "/users/password" for ::1 at 2016-09-19 20:54:04 +0530
I, [2016-09-19T20:54:04.795888 #19146]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as HTML
I, [2016-09-19T20:54:04.796108 #19146]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hXJycHI8Xmwo5D1pTS6a+naO1aV6PUDoqNw1kLjxWksF1zf+dEJ/j2KnmlOt0JSSe4F53cVP4uyBw1Pe0G4u8Q==", "user"=>{"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}
D, [2016-09-19T20:54:04.803200 #19146] DEBUG -- :   User Load (3.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["reset_password_token", "f278c026f607eea0f948e79e16861a90c9f1c73af271b2b803787f5fb68bdd04"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: In my own case disabling `registrable` doesn't affect me. You might wanna check if you have `recoverable` enabled.

Comment: It is enabled in the user model

Comment: open your irb console and run `Time.now` so we can see if the time corresponds to your local time.

Comment: `MacBook-Pro-2:website anadi$ irb
2.3.1 :001 > Time.now
 => 2016-09-17 20:30:05 +0530
2.3.1 :002 >`

Comment: I have added a comment to my answer. I hope that works. You can restart your server too before testing if it works.

Comment: Why don't you start by writing some RSpec tests? It will generally show you where the problem lies.

Comment: quite a noob at ruby but yeah, that looks like the only way to figure it out, thanks!

Comment: @AnadiMisra after writing your RSpec tests and figuring out what the problem is, kindly write what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think it's a time zone problem. You might wanna know the following about `Devise`.

**This is the list of Devise modules for your model.**

- **database_authenticatable** – Users will be able to authenticate with a login and password that are stored in the database. (password is stored in a form of a digest).
- **registerable** – Users will be able to register, update, and destroy their profiles.
- **recoverable** – Provides mechanism to reset forgotten passwords.
- **rememberable** – Enables “remember me” functionality that involves cookies.
- **trackable** – Tracks sign in count, timestamps, and IP address.
- **validatable** – Validates e-mail and password (custom validators can be used).
- **confirmable** – Users will have to confirm their e-mails after registration before being allowed to sign in.
- **lockable** – Users’ accounts will be locked out after a number of unsuccessful authentication attempts.

So, if you are having Reset Forgotten Password Problem, you might wanna make sure `recoverable` is enabled in your model.

**For example if User model** (user.rb), you will have

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable
```

Enabling `recoverable` is important to deal with your reset forgotten passwords in Devise.

Comment: Recoverable is enabled in the user model

Comment: @AnadiMisra since running `Time.now` from your `irb` gives you the correct time, then from your `devise.rb`, change the time calculation to any of this: `config.reset_password_within = 6.hours.from_now` or `config.reset_password_within = Time.now + 6.hours`. **Note**: You can do `Time.zone = "TimeZoneHere" to change your time zone. I hope this works.

Comment: initializers are loaded at startup time. You want to put in a duration not a time, otherwise once your app has been running for 6 hours, all tokens will expire.

Comment: config.confirm_within = 1.minute

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after change Rails time zone.

I can solve the problem setting to nil reset password fields on mi User model:

```rb
User.update_all(reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil)
```